# WolfSSL Settings.h File shows some error during the project building. it shows Unresolved inclution: "stm32f4xx"

Tags: c, ssl, cryptography, stm32, wolfssl

I am still studing about the WolfSSL Library. I'm usng Nucleo-STM32L476RG to run the programm.After generating the code,i try to build the code and then it shows error in settings.h file. The error shows like this
**/Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:1367:22: fatal error: stm32f4xx_hal.h: No such file or directory**

I try for solve this in many ways but non of them success. can some one help me to solve this problem

I try to make a TLS connection using WolfSSL. But it shows the error in settings.h file. i use L4 board for my works. but error shows like this
**stm32f4xx_hal.h: No such file or directory**

I try to comment this two lines because i dont need them

```
**        #elif defined(WOLFSSL_STM32F4)
            #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"**
```

after comment those lines it shows some other errors in the test.h file. it's like missing libraries.
when I try to add those libraries it shows more and more libraries.

below I put the Errors shown in the console panel

these are the errors shown in the consol panel

In file included from ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/port/st/stsafe.h:25, from ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/st/stsafe.c:22: ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:1367:22: fatal error: stm32f4xx_hal.h: No such file or directory 1367 | #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/st/stm32.c:29: ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:1367:22: fatal error: stm32f4xx_hal.h: No such file or directory 1367 | #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. In file included from ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/atmel/atmel.c:26: ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:1367:22: fatal error: stm32f4xx_hal.h: No such file or directory 1367 | #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. compilation terminated. In file included from ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/test/test.c:29: ../Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:1367:22: fatal error: stm32f4xx_hal.h: No such file or directory 1367 | #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/st/subdir.mk:22: Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/st/stsafe.o] Error 1 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/atmel/subdir.mk:19: Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/atmel/atmel.o] Error 1 make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/test/subdir.mk:19: Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/test/test.o] Error 1 make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/st/subdir.mk:22: Middlewares/Third_Party/wolfSSL_wolfSSL_wolfSSL/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/src/port/st/stm32.o] Error 1 "make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Comment: Did you try changing the `f` to `l` ?  Maybe it doesn't support STM32L4xx.

Comment: Please show the command you use to build the program. If after a change you are getting other errors, please share these errors just as well. Do not try to provide an executive summary, just copy and paste the messages without editing.

Comment: I use STM32L476RGT to build the code. these are the errors shown in the console panel.  i will put the errors shown in the console.

Comment: It seems that you have defined that you are using a **F4xx** board in the settings file. You should specify you are using a **L4xx** board in the this file: `YourProjectName/wolfSSL/wolfSSL.I-CUBE-wolfSSL_conf.h`. If you are using a new version of WolfSSL then it will probably support your STM32L476 board. So I would recommend to try to add the line `#define STM32L475xx` before line 100 somewhere so that it will include the correct files for your board.